# Android Studio Image Assets Not Showing Up Correctly

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have import 2 `.png` files to use in an Android Studio project using the method depicted in the images below:

[image: Image Asset Import Screen 1]

[image: Image Asset Import Screen 2]

I try to use the images in my `MainActivity.java` using the following code:

```
graphic1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_basketball);
graphic2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_basketball_net);
```

When I compile and run the program in the emulator, I get the following output:

[image: Application Running]

How can I make the full bitmap image appear and not just a shaded representation of the `.png` files. Thanks.

Comment: Does the actual image have the glossy gradient?

Comment: No, the image is flat.

Comment: I mean, in all these images the preview and the emulator screenshot show the gray icon. What does the real image look like?

Comment: The real image is the color basketball on the first screenshot under the source asset field.

Comment: @Chris Smith: You can copy your images directly to res/drawable folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use images in your app that you are not downloading from the internet, and you have it on your computer then all you need to do is the following...

1) Right click (two finger click if enabled on a Mac) on the image you want (basketball.png) and click "Copy".

2) Go to your folder labeled "drawable". Click on it. Now right click on it and click "Paste".

3) A new window will open called "Choose Destination Directory". Simply choose the folder you wish to save your image to. [The new window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwmXO.png)

4) Choose the file. I chose the main "drawable" folder. It just verifies the file and from where you are copying it to so hit okay.

5) Finally, edit your xml file to display your basketball image. You could do something like what I have [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odyVJ.png)

I hope this helps! If you are downloading them from the web let me know as that is completely different. Give @Dang Nguyen some credit as he said this in a comment above.